# Plot several lines in Matlab without for-loop

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I have two Nx3 matrices `P` and `Q` and each line represents a point.
I want to plot lines between the points that are in the same row of the matrices.

Following Code does it:

```
for i=1:N
  plot3( [P(i,1) Q(i,1)], ...
         [P(i,2) Q(i,2)], ...
         [P(i,3) Q(i,3)] )
end
```

Is there a way to do it without a for-loop?

If I give `plot3` the points just as vectors, Matlab draws lines between `Q(i,:)` and `P(i+1,:)` in addition to the lines I want.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
plot3([P(:, 1) Q(:, 1)]', ...
      [P(:, 2) Q(:, 2)]', ...
      [P(:, 3) Q(:, 3)]')
```

If you feed a matrix to the Matlab plotting functions, each column corresponds to one line drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want this:

```
h = quiver3(P(:,1), P(:,2), P(:,3), Q(:,1), Q(:,2) , Q(:,3),0);

set(h,'ShowArrowHead','off');
```